# Scrolling not enabling

Tags: html, css, web

I dont know why but my page is not enabling a scroll even though its already filled the whole page. why is this happening? heres my whole html code for you to understand more further my problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Guitar Corner</title>    
        <link href="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

         <script src="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
         <script src="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/jquery-1.7.1.intellisense.js"></script>
         <script src="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <style>
        .heading1
        {
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            color: black;
            text-align: right;
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)
        }
        .heading2
        {
            font-family: Bebas Neue;
            color: black;
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)
        }
        h1 
        {
            font-size:300%
        }
        .contents
        {
            background: black;
            color: black;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)\
        }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="heading1">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                            <big>
                            <big>
                                <h1>You can hear it?</h1>
                            </big>
                            </big>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <center>
                        <img src="gc.png" style="-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);"/>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="heading2">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                            <big>
                            <big>
                                <h1>Then you can sing it!</h1>
                            </big>
                            </big>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contents">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                        <br />
                            &nbsp;

                            <h2> Rock in your own way! </h2>
                            <center>
                                <img src="rockstar.jpg" class="img-rounded" width="500px" height="300px" />
                            <center>
                            <p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
                            laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper 
                            suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
                            velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim 
                            qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>      
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

pls help me in this. thanks!

Comment: lol I've found it in my bootstap.css that my overflow is hidden. by the way thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

on the css of `.contents` add `overflow-y:auto or scroll`

Hope it can help.

Comment: what div do you want to put the scroll? class="col-md-4" will adjust the height automatically depending on the content.

Comment: btw thanks, found something on my bootsrap.css that my overflow is hidden.